# Vacuum sealing jars of Simple Syrup

Tags: canning, vacuum, glucose-syrup

So I'm looking to make some simple syrups (lavender, basil, etc...).  In looking around I see that making 1:1 syrups via the "hot" process it should safely last two weeks and up to a month.

If I were to get a vacuum sealer, would that preserve it longer?  This would be a resealable system, not a one time seal process.   If the vacuum sealer would be effective what product specifically would do so?

Preliminary I was looking at this one:  [http://www.amazon.com/FoodSaver-T03-0023-01-Wide-Mouth-Jar-Sealer/dp/B00005TN7H](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005TN7H)

Perhaps there is something better or perhaps this is not meant for liquids.

Comment: Could you please add a link or description to the vacuum sealer you have in mind? Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: sure.  See above.

Comment: If you can the syrup it should be fine for a very long time, particularly if you pressure can it (which you might need to to do simply to be sure, lacking a specific recipe.) That would be "until the jar is opened" and then the clock starts ticking. Without heat, I don't know that vacuum helps in any way, and it might even hurt.

Comment: okay, I was hoping there was a way to open and reseal it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sealing a jar just to reseal it is not practical and would not help preserve the longevity of these syrups and shrubs.